# Vue 3 updating a state does not cause rerender

Tags: vuejs3

I have a custom hook I created in vue 3:
That has a function :

```js
  const cart = reactive([])

  const setCart = (productId) => {
    cart.push({
      qty: 1,
      productId 
    }) 
  }
```

However, when I use this hook in another component:

```js
const { cart } = useCart()
```

And use it to render a list, the `cart` is outdated and is not reactive. I am from a react background and would normally just call `setState` but I dont see anything similar to that so I am using `push`.

Any idea what I can do? Thanks

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you're trying to achieve? Where are you using useCart, are you using options or composition api, script setup, etc.

Comment: I actually managed to solve it, ill post what I did

Answer (score 0):

```js
const cart = ref([])

export default function useCart() {

  const setCart = (productId) => {
    cart.value = [...cart.value, {
      qty: 1,
      productId
    }]
  }
 

  return { cart, setCart }
}
```

I solved the issue listed before by globally declaring the `cart` variable instead of declaring it in the `useCart` function.
Note here I am using `ref` instead of `reactive` but it does not matter.